# Por quê obtenho resultados diferentes para os mesmos valores enviados à uma função em PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso transformar HORA em DECIMAL e depois fazer a operação contrária.
Criei as funções conforme mostro abaixo, mas o resultado não foi eficiente por que, dependendo da origem do valor, o resultado é diferente, mesmo sendo o mesmo Type.

Segue o Código:

```
<?php
// Nutro as variáveis com o mesmo valor e o mesmo tipo de Type
// Mas uma de forma direta e outra via uma function.
$A = 1.01694444444; // Esta dá o retorno errado da function Func_1
$B = Func_2('01:01:01'); // Esta dá o retorno correto da function Func_1

echo $A . '<br />' . $B;

echo "<br /><br />";

// Mas o resultado dos cálculos da function abaixo é diferente
echo Func_1($A) . '<br />' . Func_1($B);

function Func_2($time){
   $hms = explode(":", $time);
   return ($hms[0] + ($hms[1]/60) + ($hms[2]/3600));
}

function Func_1($dec){
   $seconds = ($dec * 3600);
   $hours = floor($dec);
   $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
   $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
   $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
   return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
} 

function lz($num){
   return (strlen($num) < 2) ? "0{$num}" : $num; 
}
?>
```

Já procurei em todo lugar, mas não sei como resolver isso.
Segue um LINK do exemplo acima: https://puffgestor.com.br/problema.php

Comment: Deu um `var_dump` em cada passo para ver? Tentou forçar o tipo da variável? Pelo visto é só arredondamento/precisão.

Comment: Basicamente o problema é estar trabalhando com ponto flutuante. Vai precisar de um `round( $seconds )` pra compensar. Se precisa de exatidão, não deveria estar trabalhando com float

Comment: Já tentei de tudo. Não faço idéia do que está acontecendo. 
Se eu chamar a função assim: 
$A = 1.01694444444; Func_1(''.$A..'); Colocando aspas simples, funciona. Mas da mesma forma, não funciona se o valor vier da base de dados.

Comment: Estava fazendo isso @Bacco: `$seconds = round($seconds);`

Comment: @rbz exato, é como "resolver". Mas enquanto o Jetro estiver usando essa escala, é só um paliativo. Melhor seria trabalhar com valor em segundos em inteiros, em vez de horas.

Comment: @Bacco, já tentei. Não posso arredondar por que mudaria os segundos na reconversão para HHMMSS.

Comment: @JetroBernardo só mudei a linha 20 https://ideone.com/d2dkA1 - teste com valores diversos.

Comment: @Bacco, mas se fizer no final como na minha resposta, ainda iria atrapalhar? Acho que não enxerguei o problema da escala... 

Comment: @Bacco FUNCIONOU !!! Obrigado, amigo. Eu havia tentado arredondar na linha 25, no retorno da function lz do seconds, mas não funfou. Muito obrigado, Fera.

Comment: Veja aqui um teste mais extenso para avaliar: https://ideone.com/RM1fTK

Comment: Na linha 25 não adianta fazer o round porque você ainda está usando o `$second` por conta do `-=`, assim você está subtraindo o flutuante do outro arredondado.

Comment: @rbz exatamente. Obrigado, amigo. Pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme eu já havia postado nos comentários, é um problema de arredondamento causado pelo uso do `float`.

Sugiro alteração desta maneira:

```
function Func_1($dec){
   $seconds = round($dec * 3600); // <---- acrescentado o round
   $hours = floor($dec);
   $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
   $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
   $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
   return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/RM1fTK)**.

Usando o operador de resto de divisão (`%`) e a função de formatação `sprintf` dá para simplificar um pouco, e eliminar a função `lz` completamente:

```
function Func_1($dec){
   $s       = round($dec*3600);
   $hours   = floor($dec);
   $minutes = floor(($s%3600)/60);
   $seconds = $s%60;
   return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
} 

function Func_2($time){
   $hms = explode(":", $time);
   return $hms[0] + $hms[1]/60 + $hms[2]/3600;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/9kwiWr)**.

Aqui tem um pouco de teoria que pode ajudar no entendimento:

> [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/70)

Answer (score 2):

No método `function Func_2()` você apenas trata **inteiros**.

No método `Func_1()` você está fazendo cálculos com um valor **flutuante** (`float, double, real`).

---

Uma opção de solução é arredondas as decimais dos segundos:

```
$seconds = round($seconds);
```

```
function Func_1($dec){
   $seconds = ($dec * 3600);
   $hours = floor($dec);
   $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
   $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
   $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
   $seconds = round($seconds);
   return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
}
```

Adicionado no valor de `$seconds` já com todos os cálculos para evitar erro anterior.

---

*Caso não dê certo, mostre a falha para tratarmos!*